I cannot use ckeditor5 source code content correctly in v-html
I have a panel project where I design page content and I use ckeditor5. I save the content created as a result of the design.
When I want to use the generated content from the in another project, the styles and html codes in  work fine, but the defined operations in scprit do not work.  How will I run the operations defined in scprit. (My project was written with nuxt.js)
An example of a design content I added to the source code in ckeditor:
   <style>
.menu {
    float: right;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #5fabe0;
}
.kutu {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div>
    <button id="decrement">-</button> <span id="counter">0</span> <button id="increment">+</button>
</div>
<div class="kutu">
    <p>
        <img class="foto" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Afghanistan_oil_Paintings.jpg/330px-Afghanistan_oil_Paintings.jpg">
    </p>
</div>

<script>
const decrementButton = document.getElementById('decrement');
const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');
const incrementButton = document.getElementById('increment');
let counterValue = 0;

decrementButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   counterValue--;
   updateCounter();
});

incrementButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counterValue++;
  updateCounter();
});

function updateCounter() {
  counterElement.textContent = counterValue;
}
</script>

I take this design content in my nuxt.js project and print it on the screen with v-html. This is my nuxt.js code.
<template>
    <v-container fluid class="py-0 pl-3 pr-0">

        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" class="pb-0">
                <div class="page-content-title mb-3">{{ pageContent.title }}</div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>


        <v-container fluid class="pa-0 ck-content" v-html="page"></v-container>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import '../assets/css/ckeditor5-content.css'
export default {
    setup() {
        definePageMeta({
            layout: 'menu-layout'
        })

        const apiRequests = useApiRequests();
        return { apiRequests }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            page: '',
            pageContent: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getBy();
    },
    methods: {
        async getBy() {   
             /// ilgili veriyi apiden çekme işlemleri burada tanımlanıyor.     
             this.page = response.data.content; 
        }
    }
}
</script>


The scprit operation I defined for a simple button counter increment in the design does not work. There is no problem as design and styles, they come successfully, but when you click on the increase part, nothing happens. There is no error in the code, I tested it in a simple html project and it works.
How can I run the definitions in scprit. What is the point I missed. Can't I do this?
Also one last question I can only put my html code in the ckeditor source code section. If I put a design code with nuxt.js, can I run this code with v-html in my other nuxt.js project? Can I run the defined functions?
